# Running program on shell cause Non ASCII Warning and pause the execution

Tags: shell, ascii, warnings

I installed a program from github sources with 2 computers.
On the first computer (fedora 23) everything goes well and everything work like a charm.
On the second computer (Linux 17.04), I installed from the sources with the same workflow : cmake, make install. But when I run the EXACT same thing on this computer it's not working correctly.

First, I've got this warning several times during the process :

```
WARN Non Asccii on [/PATH_TO_PROGRAM/PROGRAM] at pos 15 Num=195
```

Secondly, sometimes after this message I need to press `Enter` otherwise, the code stay in pause without doing anything (I should not press `Enter`, and the process should not go in pause).

I can't reproduce this bug on an other computer so I guess that it's not a problem from the program.
Also, I copy the compiled and installed code from computer 1 to computer 2 and I still have this problem.

Is there any update required ? And how can I know what I should update ?

Comment: If you downloaded the program from GitHub you should have the source code available. Please post at least a link to that so we can actually tell what's running. Otherwise we're just guessing. Also, I presume you mean "Ubuntu 17.04", because "Linux 17.04" does not exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

The error was about an ASCII character in my `PATH_TO_PROGRAM` at position 15